# React native The app references non-public selectors in Payload

Tags: ios, react-native

I have the following issue when I upload my React Native app to the app store

```
The app references non-public selectors in Payload/AppGeolocNative.app/AppGeolocNative: getAuthorizationStatus:, isPassthrough, newSocketQueueForConnectionFromAddress:onSocket:, onSuccess:, relativeSize, removeValuesForKeys:completion:, socket:didAcceptNewSocket:, socket:didConnectToHost:port:, socket:didConnectToUrl:, socket:didReadData:withTag:, socket:didReadPartialDataOfLength:tag:, socket:didReceiveTrust:completionHandler:, socket:didWriteDataWithTag:, socket:didWritePartialDataOfLength:tag:, socket:shouldTimeoutReadWithTag:elapsed:bytesDone:, socket:shouldTimeoutWriteWithTag:elapsed:bytesDone:, socketDidCloseReadStream:, socketDidDisconnect:withError:, socketDidSecure:, spanArray, spanArray_Count, strikeThrough, underline
```

[image]

I do not really understand what is the issue, everything is working ok, this is just a warning

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I got an email from Apple and it was telling me the reason for the error. The problem was some information I needed to add to the **info.plist** file. In my case it was the NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription.

Check if you have any email from apple which telling you what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I got this because of the build version

example :-> build version 1.0.14 to 1.0.15

[image]

[image]